# Linking two Excel workbooks which stored in different Team Sharepoint site

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 2 workbooks (master and client) which are stored in different Team Sharepoint sites ans sync to local onedrive folder. The client workbook is referring data from master workbook as following formula.

> ='https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/Shared Documents/master.xlsx'!Table1[@Price]

The problem is if I want to open client workbook, I will have to open master workbook everytime then. If not it will show #REF.

What I want in practice is when an admin updates master file's data, it would automatically update all linked files' data in each individual Team sharepoint site. How should I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately **you can’t** solve it.

It’s by design in Excel to update linked data only when both workbooks are open.